# 2013 grant read access to authenticated users without having to visit site

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-addin, authentication, people-picker, membership-provider

I have created an app which uses a people picker. The people picker needs to pickup everyone within the `NT AUTHORITY\authenticated users` group. So I have added that group to the Members group of the site.

Whilst this works, it ONLY works for authenticated users who have visited the site, those who haven't do not show up the PP results even though they are members of the `NT AUTHORITY\authenticated user`s group.

****EDIT****

Is there a way to ensure that all users have visited the site even when they've not?

OK i think we are on to something with Camerons point (thanks) i need to trigger the ensureUser but I'm not 100% sure where this should happen and how much i need to do...do i need to add to the group in code or will ensureUser handle all this for me?

Comment: I'll hazard that you can simulate the effect with SPWeb.EnsureUser(). But it may not be the best approach.